# How to adjust microphone volume using seekbar programatically in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am unable to find suitable code for adjusting Microphone volume using the seekbar programmatically. Please help me and provide me perfectly working code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the volume of the microphone; I think it has a stable threshold.

But you can change only the volume at which you can hear what you have recorded; you can check the Microphone info, I think, but I don't think you can manipulate the microphone in any way.

Checkout this link about MicrophoneInfo
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MicrophoneInfo